# Como recorrer una tupla según su posiciones para calcular valores en orden recorriendo a su vez las claves de un diccionario?

Tags: python, archivo, diccionarios

Para administrar la nueva matriz energética del Ecuador, Ud. tiene un diccionario con la información de las
plantas de energía y a las ciudades que atienden. Cada ciudad tiene: una tupla con los consumos mensuales
(12) del año en megavatios-hora (MWh) y la tarifa de consumo en dólares por megavatio-hora (MWh) que le
cobra la planta eléctrica. Una ciudad puede estar servida por más de una planta eléctrica. No todas las
ciudades son servidas por todas las plantas eléctricas.

```
consumo_energia = {'Coca Codo Sinclair':
                    {'Quito': { 'consumos':(400,432,213),'tarifa': 65},
                     'Guayaquil': { 'consumos': (120, 55, 32,70),'tarifa': 84}},
               'Sopladora': {
                    'Guayaquil':{ 'consumos': (310, 220, 321,200),'tarifa':55},
                    'Quito': { 'consumos': (400, 432,587),'tarifa': 79},
                    'Loja': { 'consumos': (50, 32, 32,40),'tarifa': 32}}}
```

Implemente lo siguiente:

Una función facturacion(consumo_energia) que recibe el diccionario consumo_energia y genera un
archivo con la facturación total en dólares de los 4 primeros meses de cada planta generadora. El
archivo resultante se llamará facturacion.txt y tendrá la siguiente estructura:

Mi codigo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
def facturacion(consumo_energia):
  total_mes = 0
  f = open("facturacion.text","w")
  f.write("Planta"+",")
  for i in range(len(lst_meses)-7):
    f.write(lst_meses[i]+",")
  for planta,sub_dic in consumo_energia.items():
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(planta+",")
    for ciudad_, sub_dic2 in sub_dic.items():  
      total_mes += (sub_dic2["consumos"] * int(sub_dic2["tarifa"]))
      f.write(str(total_mes)+",")

  f.close()
```

El problema es que no puedo conseguir los valores según los meses, es decir, el primer valor de cada tupla corresponde a enero, el segundo a febrero y así sucesivamente. Y necesito obtener el total según cada mes para todas las ciudades dentro de una planta de energía.

Asi mas o menos deberia verse el archivo creado:

```
Planta,enero,febrero,marzo,abril
Coca Codo Sinclair,2903,2145,3010,....
Sopladora,3102,3234,3223,...
```

Comment: que estas tratando de hacer aquí `sub_dic2["consumos"] * int(sub_dic2["tarifa"])`???

Answer (score 6):

Se puede optar por algo un poco más simple pero se requiere de algún conocimiento un poco avanzado de python, si conoces las comprensiones de listas y la forma de desempaquetar objetos en python entonces no tendrás problemas en entender esto.

La función `facturación` recibe el diccionario de `consumo_energia` dentro de esta función vamos a iterar en los velores de cada planta y haremos la operación para sacar el costo al momento de la iteración, esto lo hacemos con una comprensión de lista, donde haremos la operación `consumo * x["tarifa"] for consumo in x["consumos"]` que significa que multiplicaremos cada uno de los valores del consumo por la tarifa.

Para poder sacar el costo por mes se me ocurrió usar la función `zip()` que empareja datos, pero una característica de esta función es que omite los datos que no tienen el mismo tamaño que los demás, por esta razón tuve que rellenar con `0` (ya que no afecta en la suma) las listas cuya longitud sea menor a la longitud máxima de cualquier otra ciudad.

También he mejorado un poco el código utilizando la *built-in functión* `with` para la escritura del archivo y he utilizado *f-strings* para hacer todo más cómodo visualmente.

```py
def facturacion(consumo_energia):
    lst_meses = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]
  
    with open("facturacion.text","w") as f:
        f.write(f"Planta,{','.join(lst_meses)}\n") #escribimos las cabeceras

        for planta in consumo_energia.keys(): #iteramos en las ciudades de cada planta
            # sacamos el costo por cada ciudad
            consumos = [[ consumo * x["tarifa"] for consumo in x["consumos"]] for x in consumo_energia[planta].values()]
            
            maxi = len(max(consumos, key=lambda x: len(x))) #obtenemos el mes máximo
            [consumo.extend([0]*(maxi-len(consumo))) for consumo in consumos if len(consumo)<maxi] #completamos con 0 para los meses que faltan
    
            consumos_mes = [f"{sum(mes)}" for mes in zip(*consumos)] #hacemos la suma por cada mes de cada planta
            f.write(f"{planta},{','.join(consumos_mes)}\n") #escribimos
        print("fin")
```

La variable `consumos` tiene una forma `[[26000, 28080, 13845, 0], [10080, 4620, 2688, 5880]]` y como queremos mezclar o emparejar cada una de esas sub-listas usamos el operador `*` que sirve para desempaquetar nuestra matriz. Lo siento si no he explicado bien algunas cosas pero por aquí ya es un poco tarde :O.

Answer (score 3):

Si conoces y puedes usar temas "avanzados" como comprensiones de listas, acceso a `dict.items()`, uso del operador `*` para expandir listas y uso de `zip` (en este caso `zip_longest`) para agrupar elementos de diferentes listas, puedes hacer lo que buscas en un número mínimo de líneas (al final de esta respuesta pongo un ejemplo).

Sin embargo el código resultante puede ser bastante ilegible para quien no conozca muy bien el lenguaje, pues está haciendo uso de características muy "pythónicas" que otros lenguajes no tienen o que requerirían diferente sintaxis.

Pero todos estos temas "avanzados" no son más que atajos sintácticos
("azúcar" dicen algunos) para escribir código más compacto, pero lo mismo puedes hacer con estructuras de control más "normales" (bucles, condicionales). Este segundo enfoque tiene la ventaja de que es más fácilmente traducible a otros lenguajes, y por tanto más fácil de comprender para lectores que vengan de otros lenguajes, o que están empezando.

Por tanto comienzo mi respuesta dando una de estas soluciones sencillas, que sería la siguiente:

### Solución convencional

```
def facturacion(consumo_energia):
  f = open("facturacion2.txt", "w")
  f.write("Planta,enero,febrero,marzo,abril\n")
  for planta in consumo_energia:
    f.write(planta+",")
    datos = consumo_energia[planta]
    for i in range(4): # 4 meses
      total = 0
      for ciudad in datos:
        consumos = datos[ciudad]["consumos"]
        tarifa = datos[ciudad]["tarifa"]
        if i < len(consumos):
          total += consumos[i] * tarifa
      f.write(str(total)+",")
    f.write("\n")
  f.close()
```

El código es casi autoexplicativo, salvo un par de detalles:

- Cuando se hace `for elemento in diccionario` lo que se van obteniendo son las claves de ese diccionario. Posteriormente se pueden obtener los valores usando `diccionario[elemento]`
- Hay un `for i in range(4)` para obtener solo los cuatro primeros elementos (meses) de consumo. Pero quizás algunas ciudades tengan menos. Por eso es necesario un `if i < len(consumos)` para evitar acceder a elementos que no existan en esa ciudad.
- La lógica del código es: para cada mes entre 0 y 3, se recorre la lista de ciudades para ir sumando los consumos correspondientes a ese mes en cada ciudad. Esa suma se realiza sobre la variable `total`, y una vez recorridas todas las ciudades, se vuelca a fichero ese total (que se vuelve a poner a 0 al pasar al mes siguiente).

### Solución avanzada

Haciendo uso de construcciones "pythónicas" como las que mencioné al inicio del post, la función puede quedar mucho más compacta:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def facturacion(consumo_energia):
  f = open("facturacion.txt", "w")
  print("Planta,enero,febrero,marzo,abril", file=f)
  for planta, datos in consumo_energia.items():
     consumos = [ [c*x["tarifa"] for c in x["consumos"]] for x in datos.values() ]
    totales = [ sum(c) for c in zip_longest(*consumos, fillvalue=0) ]
    print(planta, *totales, sep=",", file=f)
  f.close()
```

Las características "avanzadas" que estoy usando son:

- Iterar sobre `diccionario.items()` para obtener a la vez la clave y el valor de cada elemento del diccionario
- Comprensiones de listas como la que se asigna a `consumos` (que en este caso contiene a su vez otra comprensión de listas anidada) para crear otras listas auxiliares (en este caso sería una lista con los gastos en dolares de cada ciudad, en cada mes)
- Uso de `zip_longest()` para iterar por listas de listas agrupando términos. Cada elemento retornado por `zip_longest()` es una tupla con los datos del primer mes, del segundo mes, etc.. Si alguna de las listas de consumos es más corta, se rellena con ceros (eso hace `fillvalue=0`).
- Uso del operador `*` delante de un parámetro para "expandirlo". Si el parámetro es una lista, cada uno de sus elementos se convierte en un parámetro separado para la función.
- Uso de `sum()` para sumar los elementos de un iterable sin tener que escribir otro bucle.
- Uso de `print()` para volcar al fichero, haciendo uso de sus opciones `file=` para indicar el fichero, o `sep=` para indicar el separador a usar entre los datos volcados.

Como ves, la legibilidad del código ha empeorado mucho, especialmente si todas estas características son nuevas para tí. Por ello seguramente será preferible el enfoque de la solución convencional.

Comment: Usar la función `zip_longest` ahorra bastante trabajo, yo evite usar módulos por que con el enunciado se puede saber que es una tarea y una condición puede ser no usar módulos. De todas formas muy buena solución :D